# json_encode() - how to get original data back?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I"m using the function json_encode() to encode my data in php before sending it back to my page.  However, single quotes and double quotes have been escaped and appear as /' and /" in javascript.  Any idea how to get back those quotes without those slashes in javascript.  I'm using jquery.

Comment: @alex-- didn't pay attention ... deleted the answer :p ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`$.parseJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) if your JSON is a string.

If after that, you *still* have slashes, you may have magic quotes on. Check with this...

```
var_dump(get_magic_quotes_gpc());
```

If you get `TRUE`, disable magic quotes.

Comment: I don't have magic quotes on, but still showing those escaped quotes.

Comment: @the_archer If you do `json_decode()` on it in PHP, do you get the same data back (with slashes)?

Comment: @the_archer OK, try and remove them from your PHP strings first. You should be able to get away with `stripslashes()`.

Comment: @the_archer You should ideally try and figure out what was adding those slashes though :)

Comment: I'm using mysql_real_escape_string() on the data to be sent to mysql, that's probably it.

Comment: @the_archer Yeah, that wouldd be it. You should only use that on strings about to be used in SQL.

Comment: yes, the data is being entered in mysql and again fetched to be given to script so that I can append new added data dynamically to page.  Ajaxed comments script, that's what I'm working on.